# Is there a way to get assembled query by Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Criteria?

Tags: php, model, criteria, phalcon

I've not found here how we can get builded query by Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Criteria in docs:
http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Criteria.html

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Criteria builds an array of valid parameters for SomeModel::find, or SomeModel::findFirst, this class does not build a real query.

Furthermore, we have Phalcon\Mvc\Query\Builder this class has the ability to build PHQL queries:

```
<?php

//Get the PHQL to be generated
$phql = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
    ->from('Robots')
    ->limit(20);
    ->order('Robots.name')
    ->getPhql();

//Execute the query
$robots = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
    ->from('Robots')
    ->limit(20);
    ->order('Robots.name')
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

More info: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html#creating-queries-using-the-query-builder